# How do I use the onsubmit function in Django to switch pages?

Tags: html, django, forms, submit

I'm trying to create a page that, once a form submit button is clicked, will redirect to the home page. I'm using the 'onsubmit' function for that, but it isn't working.

HTML code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}{% load static %} 
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'login.css' %}" />
<script src="{% static 'login.js'}"></script>
{% endblock %}

<!-- page code -->
{% block pagename %}
<p>SIGN IN</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="contentContainer">
    <p>Please enter your competition ID:</p>
    <form class="form" onsubmit="pageSwitch()">
        <input type="text" id="entry" placeholder="ID ENTRY HERE...">
        <input type="submit" id="entrySubmit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

JS Code

```
function pageSwitch(){
    window.location.replace("{% url 'home' %}");
}
```

`urls.py` Code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from files import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test/', views.test, name='test'),
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('leaderboard/', views.lboard, name='lboard'),
    path('scorecard/', views.score, name='score'),
    path('submit/', views.submit, name='submit'),
    path('base/', views.base, name='base'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

'views.py' Code

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')

def base(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def lboard(request):
    return render(request, 'leaderboard.html')

def score(request):
    return render(request, 'score.html')

def submit(request):
    return render(request, 'submit.html')

def base(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

I'm not really sure what else to try, I've been messing around with either using anchors and 'onclick' instead, but that hasn't worked either, so I'm a bit stuck. This is my first time using Django, so all of the other explanations I've found have been a bit too complex for me to understand, including things that aren't in my code that have thrown me off a bit.